# Is Armenian and Somali languages/locales support for android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, localization, locale

I have requirement in my application for language support of Armenian and Somali both android and IOS , but i can't find any document related to armenian and Somali languages.If anyone know about this please help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
 please follow below link it may be use full
```

http://snowpard-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html

step 1:
  create value folder for Armenian  (values-hy)
  eg:

```
 <string name="app_name">Հղրդգրթ</string>
 <string name="hello_world">Պարամետրեր</string>
```

step 2: based on your requirment u should write below code

```
eg: mtextView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Locale locale = new Locale("hy");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            updateText();
        }
    });
  public void updateText(){
 mtextView1.setText(R.string.hello_world);
  }
```